# How can i find my propertyinfo type?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have the following code:

```
 public class EntityBase
{


 public virtual void Freez(EntityBase obj)
 {
    //TO DO

 }
```

Any Class in my sample inherit from EntityBase; like this:

```
  public class Person:EntityBase
    {
       public Person()
       {
           this.PersonAsset = new Asset { Title = "asset1" };
       }
        public string Name { get; set; }
       public Asset PersonAsset{get;set;}


    }
   public class Asset : EntityBase
   {
       public string Title { get; set; }
   }
```

I want when i invoke person.Freez() if person has a property that is a class such as PersonAsset.the PersonAsset Freez() method raised;
I think i must using reflection in EntityBase Freez() method.But when i get PersonAsset property
by reflection how can i raise its Freez() method?Or How can i find my propertyinfo is a Class?

Comment: Something wrong with the design of solution you've provided, you are trying to hard code in a base class a behaviour which is very specific for nested class implementation (it has PersonAsset property). Describe please what you are trying to achieve in terms of business logic.

Comment: i want when i invoke my person class Freeze() method any Property in myclass that inherit from EntityBase invoke their Freez() method?

Comment: Since it's possible for a Freezable entity to contain other Freezable entities you'll need to guard against cyclical references, otherwise you'll encounter non-terminating loops...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public virtual void Freez()
{
    foreach (var prop in this.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (prop.PropertyType.IsClass && typeof(EntityBase).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
        {
            var value = (EntityBase) prop.GetValue(this, null);
            value.Freez();
        }

        if (typeof(ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
        {
            var collection = (ICollection)prop.GetValue(this, null);
            if (collection != null)
            {
                foreach (var obj in collection)
                {
                    if (obj is EntityBase)
                    {
                        ((EntityBase)obj).Freez();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tnk You Sjoerd.i want wonderid if my public Asset PersonAsset{get;set;}
 was public List<Asset> PersonAsset{get;set;} ...Can i do your Solution form any item in my list?

Comment: I edited my code to also loop through all collections looking for EntityBase objects.